# How can I get the Max id of a table or 1 if empty using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

i manually insert the id of a table by selecting the max id from the table and increment it by 1. how do i do that with c# and linq if the table is empty and the max returns null i'm using the below code but it is giving the error "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type"

```
var t = (from tab1 in db.questions select tab1.QuestionId1).Max();
            if (t!=null)
            {
                 qui = t + 1;
            }

            else
            {
                 qui = 1;
            }
```

Comment: If your entity has surrogate PK, the responsibility to give them it, is on the DB side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not the preferred method to get "new ids" (better have the database generate them), but here it goes:

```
var maxId = ((from tab1 in db.questions select (int?)tab1.QuestionId1).Max() ?? 0) + 1;
```

Or the equivalent, but IMO easier to read:

```
var maxId = (db.questions.Select(x => (int?)x.QuestionId1).Max() ?? 0) + 1
```

Your original problem is that you are calling `Max()` using a `IEnumerable<int>` parameter, and that doesn't allow it to return an empty value (it throws an exception) since the return value is `int` and `int` can't be `null`.

I'm casting the enumerable returned by `Select()` to an enumerable of `Nullable<int>` (or `int?` for short) types, so `Max()` returns an `int?` which allows it to return `null` if the enumerable is empty (as it's the case when no rows are selected), instead of throwing a exception.

Comment: Would that still work if there's nothing in the table, though?

Comment: I think so, since I'm casting the selection to `int?` so it allows `Max()` to return `null`. Haven't tested though, it's out of my head. It'd use this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302925(v=vs.100).aspx which, according to the remarks, returns `null` if it's an empty set.

Comment: that's it thank you very much. it worked great for me. the problem is i need to know the id to insert it in some tables as foreign key in the same action. but if you have a better approach i would really appreciate it if you share it with me. i'm fairly new to this. thank you again

Comment: If you need to do it manually, you could create the entity, have it an id assigned by the database, read it back (or have it returned by your `INSERT` statement with an `OUTPUT` SQL clause), then assign it to the foreign entity. If you use an ORM (like Entity Framework) all of this is taken care of for you on a higher level.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work?

```
// Assume we want to start with id 1
var maxId = db.Questions
    .Max(q => q.QuestionId1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max();

return maxId + 1;
```

[`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb356814.aspx) will handle the empty table case.

Databases usually have an auto incremented id feature. If you are using Entity Framework then it should be enabled by default.

Comment: What happens if there's nothing in the table, though?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for something like this, using LINQ's Extension Method syntax:

```
var maxID = db.Questions.Any() 
            ? db.Questions.Max(q => QuestionId1) + 1
            : 1
```

If there are any `Questions` in the database grab the highest `QuestionId1` and increment by 1. Otherwise return 1.